# jQuery AJAX pagination returning same results from db

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, jquery-pagination

I'm using jQuery AJAX pagination for my terms search and two out of 4 tables have links in one of their columns.Idea that i have is that i want to be able to click on some of those links and to search other table for the value of that link that i clicked.

The problem is that pagination works normally only on tables with links but not on the other 2 tables that have been searched for by clicked link value.Problem occurs as ajax returning same 10,30,50 (per page) results when i click on first 10 pages of pagination if there is 10+ pages.If there is less then 10 pages total, returned results will be same on all pages except on the last page.Further more results that i'm getting on first and other pages (except last one,or the ones over 10th page) are 10 to 20 from database if,of course, per page is 10.Here is the both PHP and jQuery code:

**jQuery**

```
    $('html').hide().fadeIn(800)

          $("#poc").click(function(){
          $("#search-link").val("")
          $(this).hide().fadeIn(800)
          $(this).addClass('aktivan')
          $("#form").hide()
          $("#form2").hide()
          $("#fail").hide()
          $("#kontejner").hide()
          $("#pret").removeClass('aktivan')
          if ($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Pretraži"){
          $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Unesite termin u polje za pretragu i stisnite na "Pretraži"</p>').hide().fadeIn(800)
          } else if ($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Претражи"){
          $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите термин у поље за претрагу и стисните на "Претражи"</p>').hide().fadeIn(800)
          }
          }).addClass('aktivan')

          $("#pret").click(function(){
          $("#search-link").val("")
          $("#fail").hide()
          $("#kontejner").hide()
          $("#form").hide()
          $("#form2").hide()
          $(this).hide().fadeIn(800)
          $(this).addClass('aktivan')
          $("#poc").removeClass('aktivan')
          if ($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Pretraži"){
          $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Unesite ICS oznaku u polje za pretragu i stisnite na "Pretraži"</p>').hide().fadeIn(800)
          } else if($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Претражи"){
          $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите ICS ознаку у поље за претрагу и стисните на "Претражи"</p>').hide().fadeIn(800)
          }
          })

       $("#jezik").toggle(function(){

           $("html").hide().fadeIn(800)
           $("#slika").attr('src','slike/logo_big_rs_cyr.jpg')
           $("#jezik").html("Srpski LAT")
           $("h1").html("Терминолошка база")
           $("#poc").html("Претрага термина")
           $("#pret").html("Претрага по ICS-у")
           if ($("#poc").hasClass('aktivan')){
           $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите термин у поље за претрагу и стисните на "Претражи"</p>')
           } else if ($("#pret").hasClass('aktivan')){
           $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите ICS ознаку у поље за претрагу и стисните на "Претражи"</p>')
           }
           $("#nr").text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("termin","термин").replace("termini","термини");
           })
           $("#pretragaDug").attr('value','Претражи')
           $("#fail").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите термин у поље за претрагу</p>')
           $("#prazan").html("Термин или ознака није пронађен(а). Унесите други термин/ознаку")
           $("#1").html("Термин (sr)")
           $("#2").html("Дефиниција (sr)")
           $("#3").html("Термин (en)")
           $("#4").html("Дефиниција (en)")
           $("#5").html("Тачка")
           $("#6").html("Ознака нац. станд.")
           $("#7").html("Ознака комисије")
           $("#11").html("Код")
           $("#12").html("Дефиниција (sr)")
           $("#13").html("Дефиниција (en)")
           $("#14").html("Дефиниција (fr)")
           $("#15").html("Дефиниција (de)")
           $("#21").html("Термин (sr)")
           $("#22").html("Дефиниција (sr)")
           $("#23").html("Термин (en)")
           $("#24").html("Дефиниција (en)")
           $("#25").html("Тачка")
           $("#26").html("Ознака комисије")
           $("#31").html("Одељак")
           $("#32").html("Ознака нац. станд.")
           $("#33").html("Ознака стандарда")
           $("#34").html("Термин (en)")
           $("#35").html("Дефиниција (en)")
           $("#36").html("Термин (sr)")
           $("#37").html("Дефиниција (sr)")
           $('li.active,li.inactive').text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("Prva","Прва").replace("Prethodna","Претходна").replace("Sledeća","Следећа").replace("Poslednja","Последња");
           })
           $(".total").text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("Strana","Страна").replace("od","од");
           })
           $("#go_btn").attr('value','Иди на страну')              
           $("#per_btn").attr('value','Број редова по страни')
           $("#footer p").html("Институт за стандардизацију Србије | Стевана Бракуса 2, 11030 Београд | тел. 00381 11 7541-421, 3409-301 | Инфоцентар тел. 00381 11 6547-293, 3409-384")

           },function(){

           $("html").hide().fadeIn(800)
           $("#slika").attr('src','slike/logo_big_la.jpg')
           $("#jezik").html("Српски CYR")
           $("h1").html("Terminološka baza")
           $("#poc").html("Pretraga termina")
           $("#pret").html("Pretraga po ICS-u")
           if ($("#poc").hasClass('aktivan')){
           $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Unesite termin u polje za pretragu i stisnite na "Pretraži"</p>')
           } else if ($("#pret").hasClass('aktivan')){
           $("#uputstvo").html('<p class="tekst">Unesite ICS oznaku u polje za pretragu i stisnite na "Pretraži"</p>')
           }
           $("#nr").text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("термин","termin").replace("термини","termin");
           })
           $("#pretragaDug").attr('value','Pretraži')
           $("#fail").html('<p class="tekst">Unesite termin u polje za pretragu</p>')
           $("#prazan").html("Termin ili oznaka nije pronadjen(a). Unesite drugi termin/oznaku")
           $("#1").html("Termin (sr)")
           $("#2").html("Definicija (sr)")
           $("#3").html("Termin (en)")
           $("#4").html("Definicija (en)")
           $("#5").html("Tačka")
           $("#6").html("Oznaka nac. stand.")
           $("#7").html("Oznake komisije")
           $("#11").html("Kod")
           $("#12").html("Definicija (sr)")
           $("#13").html("Definicija (en)")
           $("#14").html("Definicija (fr)")
           $("#15").html("Definicija (de)")
           $("#21").html("Termin (sr)")
           $("#22").html("Definicija (sr)")
           $("#23").html("Termin (en)")
           $("#24").html("Definicija (en)")
           $("#25").html("Tačka")
           $("#26").html("Oznake komisije")
           $("#31").html("Odeljak")
           $("#32").html("Oznaka nac. stand.")
           $("#33").html("Oznaka standarda")
           $("#34").html("Termin (en)")
           $("#35").html("Definicija (en)")
           $("#36").html("Termin (sr)")
           $("#37").html("Definicija (sr)")
           $('li.active,li.inactive').text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("Прва","Prva").replace("Претходна","Prethodna").replace("Следећа","Sledeća").replace("Последња","Poslednja");
           })
           $(".total").text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace("Страна","Strana").replace("од","od");
           })
           $("#go_btn").attr('value','Idi na stranu')              
           $("#per_btn").attr('value','Broj redova po strani')
           $("#footer p").html("Institut za standardizaciju Srbije | Stevana Brakusa 2, 11030 Beograd | tel. 00381 11 7541-421,3409-301 | Infocentar tel. 00381 11 6547-293, 3409-384")  
            })

    $("#pretragaDug").click(function(){

        if ($("#search-text").val() != ""){

            function loadData(page){

                if ($("#poc").hasClass('aktivan') && $("#search-link").val()==""){
                    var baza = 1;
                    var search = $("#search-text").val();
                } else if ($("#pret").hasClass('aktivan') && $("#search-link").val()==""){
                    var baza = 2;
                    var search = $("#search-text").val();
                }  
                if ($("#poc").hasClass('aktivan') && $("#search-link").val()!=""){
                    var baza = 3;
                    var search = $("#search-link").val();
                } else if ($("#pret").hasClass('aktivan') && $("#search-link").val()!=""){
                    var baza = 4;
                    var search = $("#search-link").val();
                }
                var perpage = $("#select").val();
                var jezik = $("#pretragaDug").val();

                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: {search:search,page:page,perpage:perpage,jezik:jezik,baza:baza},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#uputstvo").hide() 
                        $("#fail").hide()
                        $("#form").hide().fadeIn()
                        $("#form2").hide().fadeIn()
                        $("#kontejner").html(data).hide().fadeIn()
                    }
                });
            }

            loadData(1);    // For first time page load default results
            $('.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);
                $(this).unbind('click').bind('click');
            });

            $(".linktab1").live('click',function(){
                var search1 = $(this).text();
                var page = 1;
                $("#search-link").val(search1);
                loadData(page);
                $(this).unbind('click').bind('click');

            })

            $(".linktab2").live('click',function(){
                var search2 = $(this).text();
                var page = 1;
                $("#search-link").val(search2);
                loadData(page);
                $(this).unbind('click').bind('click');

            })

            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                    $(this).unbind('click').bind('click');
                }else if ($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Pretraži"){
                    alert('Unesite broj strane između 1 i '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    alert('Унесите број између 1 и '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }    
            });

            $('#per_btn').live('click',function(){
                var perpage = $("#select").val();
                var page = $(".active").attr('p');
                loadData(page);
                $(this).unbind('click').bind('click');
            });   

        } else if ($("#search-text").val() == "") {
        $("#form").hide()
        $("#form2").hide()
        $("#uputstvo").hide()
        $("#kontejner").hide()
        if ($("#pretragaDug").val()=="Pretraži"){    
          $("#fail").fadeIn(800)
          } else {
          $("#fail").html('<p class="tekst">Унесите термин у поље за претрагу</p>').fadeIn(800)
          }

      } 

    })
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];
$baza = $_GET['baza'];
$search = $_GET['search'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
if ($_GET['perpage']==""){
$per_page = 10;
} else {
$per_page = $_GET['perpage'];
}
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include "connection.php";


$limit='OFFSET '.$start.' ROWS FETCH NEXT '.$per_page.' ROWS ONLY';

if ($baza==1){

    $tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM tcpr WHERE TerSrp LIKE '%$search%' OR TerEng LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC $limit";
    $query_pag_num = "SELECT * FROM tcpr WHERE TerSrp LIKE '%$search%' OR TerEng LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC";
} else if ($baza==2){

    $tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM ics WHERE code LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC $limit";
    $query_pag_num = "SELECT * FROM ics WHERE code LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC";
} else if ($baza==3){

    $tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM tcpr WHERE OznNacstand LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC $limit";
    $query_pag_num = "SELECT * FROM tcpr WHERE OznNacstand LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC";
} else if ($baza==4){

    $tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM icsprikaz WHERE code LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC $limit";
    $query_pag_num = "SELECT * FROM icsprikaz WHERE code LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY code ASC";
}

$result_pag_data = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tableQuery);

$result_pag_num = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query_pag_num,array(),array("Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($result_pag_num);

if ($count==0){
    exit ('<p id="prazan" class="tekst">Termin ili oznaka nije pronadjen(a). Unesite drugi termin/oznaku</p><script>$("#form2").css("display","none");$("#form").css("display","none")</script>');
    } else if ($count==1 && $_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    echo '<div id="nr">'.$count.' termin</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>'; 
    } else if ($count==1 && $_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    echo '<div id="nr">'.$count.' термин</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    } else if ($count > 1 && $_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    echo '<div id="nr">'.$count.' termina</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>';    
    } else if ($count > 1 && $_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    echo '<div id="nr">'.$count.' термина</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }

$rezultat = "";

if (isset($search) && ($baza==1)){
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $rezultat .= "<tr><td>".$row['TerSrp']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefSrp']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['TerEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['Odeljak']."</td>".
                "<td><a class='linktab1' href='#'>".$row['OznNacstand']."</a></td>".
                "<td>".$row['code']."</td></tr>";

}} else if (isset($search) && ($baza==2)){
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $rezultat .= "<tr><td><a class='linktab2' href='#'>".$row['code']."</a></td>".
                "<td>".$row['description']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['description_en']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['description_fr']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['description_de']."</td></tr>";

}} else if (isset($search) && ($baza==3)){
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $rezultat .= "<tr><td>".$row['TerSrp']."</a></td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefSrp']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['TerEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['Odeljak']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['code']."</td></tr>";

}} else if (isset($search) && ($baza==4)){
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $rezultat .= "<tr><td>".$row['Odeljak']."</a></td>".
                "<td>".$row['OznNacstand']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['OznStand']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['TerEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefEng']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['TerSrp']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['DefSrp']."</td></tr>";
}}

if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži" && $_GET['baza']==1){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="8%">
            <tr>
                <th id="1">Termin (sr)</th>
                <th id="2">Definicija (sr)</th>
                <th id="3">Termin (en)</th>
                <th id="4">Definicija (en)</th>
                <th id="5">Tačka</th>
                <th id="6">Oznaka nac. stand.</th>
                <th id="7">Oznake komisije</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';

} else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи" && $_GET['baza']==1){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="8%">
            <tr>
                <th id="1">Термин (sr)</th>
                <th id="2">Дефиниција (sr)</th>
                <th id="3">Термин (en)</th>
                <th id="4">Дефиниција (en)</th>
                <th id="5">Тачка</th>
                <th id="6">Ознака нац. станд.</th>
                <th id="7">Ознаке комисија</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';    
}

if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži" && $_GET['baza']==2){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <tr>
                <th id="11">Kod</th>
                <th id="12">Definicija (sr)</th>
                <th id="13">Definicija (en)</th>
                <th id="14">Definicija (fr)</th>
                <th id="15">Definicija (de)</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';

} else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи" && $_GET['baza']==2){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="5%">
            <col width="20%">
            <col width="20%">
            <col width="20%">
            <col width="20%">
            <tr>
                <th id="11">Код</th>
                <th id="12">Дефиниција (sr)</th>
                <th id="13">Дефиниција (en)</th>
                <th id="14">Дефиниција (fr)</th>
                <th id="15">Дефиниција (de)</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';    
}

if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži" && $_GET['baza']==3){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="13%">
            <tr>
                <th id="21">Termin (sr)</th>
                <th id="22">Definicija (sr)</th>
                <th id="23">Termin (en)</th>
                <th id="24">Definicija (en)</th>
                <th id="25">Tačka</th>
                <th id="26">Oznake komisije</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';

} else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи" && $_GET['baza']==3){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="13%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="13%">
            <tr>
                <th id="21">Термин (sr)</th>
                <th id="22">Дефиниција (sr)</th>
                <th id="23">Термин (en)</th>
                <th id="24">Дефиниција (en)</th>
                <th id="25">Тачка</th>
                <th id="26">Ознаке комисија</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';
}


if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži" && $_GET['baza']==4){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <tr>
                <th id="31">Odeljak</th>
                <th id="32">Oznaka nac. stand.</th>
                <th id="33">Oznaka standarda</th>
                <th id="34">Termin (en)</th>
                <th id="35">Definicija (en)</th>
                <th id="36">Termin (sr)</th>
                <th id="37">Definicija (sr)</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';

} else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи" && $_GET['baza']==4){

echo $tabela = '<table id="Tabela" class="sortable">
            <col width="8%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <col width="15%">
            <col width="25%">
            <tr>
                <th id="31">Одељак</th>
                <th id="32">Ознака нац. станд.</th>
                <th id="33">Ознака стандарда</th>
                <th id="34">Термин (en)</th>
                <th id="35">Дефиниција (en)</th>
                <th id="36">Термин (sr)</th>
                <th id="37">Дефиниција (sr)</th>
            </tr>'.$rezultat.'</table>';   
}



$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}

if ($count <= 10){
$msg = "";
} else {*/
$msg = "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>Prva</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>Прва</li>";
    }
} else if ($first_btn) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>Prva</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>Прва</li>";
    }
}

if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Prethodna</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
     $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Претходна</li>";
    }
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Prethodna</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Претходна</li>";
    }
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#4C5D6D;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Sledeća</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Следећа</li>";
    }
} else if ($next_btn) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Sledeća</li>";
    } else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Следећа</li>";
    }
}

if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Poslednja</li>";
    }else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Последња</li>";
    }
} else if ($last_btn) {
    if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Poslednja</li>";
    }else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Последња</li>";
    }
}
if ($_GET['jezik']=="Pretraži"){
$total_string = "<div class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Strana <b>".$cur_page."</b> od <b>$no_of_paginations</b></div>";
} else if ($_GET['jezik']=="Претражи"){
$total_string = "<div class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Страна <b>".$cur_page."</b> од <b>$no_of_paginations</b></div>";
}
$msg = $msg."</ul></div>".$total_string;  // Content for pagination
$msg = $msg."<div style='clear:both;'></div>".'<div id="print"><a href="#" onClick="window.print()"><img class="slike" src="slike/print_icon.gif" /></a></div>'; 
echo $msg;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
            sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById('Tabela'));
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or mssql?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late,im using SQL Server 2012 Express but i manage to solve the problem. Apparently the problem was with  "ORDER BY" since i was trying to order by "code" that wasnt in the table column. I just changed to ORDER BY some other column that is showing in table and it works fine now.Problem occurred maybe because im using sortable.js